# Amazon S3 Setup for Craft 3

Tags: craft3, s3, aws

I'm attempting to setup a craft site with AWS S3/ Cloudfront.  I found this tutorial (from some time ago):
https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-aws-s3-buckets-cloudfront-distribution-with-craft-cms

I'm not seeming to get this to work though.  Here's a run down of what I did.
I had a site that we are migrating to new hosting. All asset files were on an S3/cloudfront combo.

I had copies of all assets, and re-uploaded them to a new amazon account in an s3 bucket. The tutorial link took me through the process:

I made an s3 bucket named `mysitecontent` (this isn't the real bucket name) I made it to block all public access and added this bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mysitecontent/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::196144777777:distribution/E25EJ0AJ777777"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

(numbers changed to protect the innocent!) I didn't make any other changes.

Then I created a cloudfront Distribution (E25EJ0AJ777777 -number changed again!)

I set it's origin to the `s3-mysitecontent-bucket` with a domain of mysitecontent.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com. Origin access was set to 'origin access control settings".  (i'm not sure if that should have been legacy access identities.)

Then in IAM, I created a policy `mysite-content-bucket-access` using this Json

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "cloudfront:GetDistribution",
                "cloudfront:GetStreamingDistribution",
                "cloudfront:GetDistributionConfig",
                "cloudfront:ListDistributions",
                "cloudfront:ListCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentities",
                "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation",
                "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
                "cloudfront:ListInvalidations",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "waf:GetWebACL",
                "waf:ListWebACLs"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mysitecontent"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mysitecontent/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I created a group called `s3-mysitecontent-group`. and added my `mysitecontent-bucket-access` to that group.

Lastly I added a new user `mssitecontent-user` to the group.

Since this site was being migrated I went into my volumes in the Craft dashboard and changed the S3 settings for each folder in my S3 bucket (each folder is set to a separate asset) to my new user credentials and AWS details.

Here is the problem. In the Craft dashboard, I go to media and can upload, and it works and when I go into details of the media, if I click download the asset (in this case an image) downloads, but no thumbnails show up for the image and in the frontend I get broken images.

If I look in my AWS S3 dashboard the newly uploaded images don't show up in any of the bucket directories or in the bucket at all.

Is there any way to actually test this connection and make sure it's working properly or did I blatantly miss something in my setup?